# Connect localhost for SQL Server on DBeaver (MAC)

Tags: sql-server, database, dbeaver

I tried to connect SQL Server on DBeaver with localhost but I'm getting this error, what can be the cause of it? I'm using a Mac, on Windows I was able to do this without changing any parameters. Should I use localhost? Maybe the port number might be wrong.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: DBeaver is just a client application like SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). It doesn't install an SQL Server instance anywhere. If you want to run an SQL Server instance on your macOS machine you probably need to look into Docker and create a [SQL Server container](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) from `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest` or `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest`.